# Building vs 2010 project in vs 2012 creates not always working executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, x86

I've got this weird problem. On my machine, with both VS2010 and VS2012 installed, I've worked further on a VS2010 project from someone else, but I did it in VS2012 because I want all projects to use the same development environment.
I added some RFCs and fixed some bugs so I wanted to test this new software on another Windows 7 machine and it simply does nothing when I try to run the exe, not even log anything, the process just stays in the Processes overview about 10 seconds and then disappears again and nothing is logged.

I've tried my version again but first I added more, and earlier, logging with System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine making the code look like this:

```
static class Program
{
    internal static Denocard.DCLib.Global global = new Denocard.DCLib.Global(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} - Program.main 1", DateTime.Now));
```

As that didn't log anything either I took the original Debug folder from the original project and tried that. It works on the test machine and logs into the log file, so I was wondering what would happen when I would build that original project.

So I copied the original project again, opened it in VS2012 and did a clean and build to see if the exe in that Debug folder would work implicating I messed something up. But that also didn't work ...

So, there must be something between VS 2010 and VS2012 that's messing things up, or it has to do with my computer. I've got Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and my best guess is that the previous developer used a Windows 7 32 bit system.

I've also tried another computer with Windows 7 32 bit to see if the problems weren't client-specific, but that didn't work either so it seems a build-machine / Visual Studio version problem to me.

Additional info:
- I've looked at the settings for the 3 projects that together turn into 1 application and at the configuration properties I see that 2 of them have 'Any CPU' as platform, but the main project has x86 as platform.
- the .Net version in the config file has been 4 all the time and both my computer as the test computer currently at my desk have version 4.0.30319 so that should be the same.

Anyone with an idea on what's going on here and / or how to solve this?

**edit**
Installed windbg on the system to get to the core exception or error. In Windbg it seems to be an CLR error, although it doesn't state which. In the Windows event log (found that tip here: [Crash dump with unknown origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017117/crash-dump-with-unknown-origin)) it says System.TypeInitializationException at Program.Main(System.String[]). Now we're getting somewhere, although it doesn't say what type initialization is causing the exception ...

Comment: Where are you trying to view output from System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine?

Comment: In ..\Logs\ECM.log as that's where it's configured to go in App.config:       <listeners>
        <add name="TextWriter" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="..\Logs\ECM.log" />
      </listeners>